# Ext4 Permissions for bind mounting

Tags: mount, dropbox, ubuntu-mate

I'm currently using Dropbox (although alternatives are welcome!) to sync my work files.

Since symbolic links no longer work with Dropbox, we have to use a bind mount to reference other areas of the system outside of `/home/me/Dropbox`:

```
mount --bind /var/www /home/me/Dropbox/var/www
```

I have set up the following in fstab:

```
/var/www /home/me/Dropbox/var/www none defaults,bind,x-gvfs-hide 0 0
```

This works fine for this location since permissions on `/var/www` are `0755`

I want to go further and add `/var/lib/mysql` to my sync locations but permissions here are `0700`. It makes sense that Dropbox can't read this and the only solutions I have found regarding permissions is to `chown` or `chmod` them which I don't want to do in this case. I understand that ext4 can't handle `uid/gid` options either.

Any sugesstions/workarounds?